# How is boolean expression A*B + C*(A⊕B) equal to A*B + C*B + A*C

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm having trouble trying to simplify one boolean equation into another (and visa versa).

Why are these Boolean expressions,

> A.B + C.(A⊕B) = A.B + C.B + A.C

equal?

They have the same truth table but I cannot figure out how one simplifies into the other.
Here is what I have attempted so far:

> A.B + C.(A⊕B)
>
> A.B + C.(A'.B + A.B')  ...XOR equivelent
>
> A.B + C.A'.B + C.A.B' ...distributive

I don't know what else I can do. If I try from the other direction, it still does not work:

> A.B + C.B + A.C
>
> A.B + C.(B + A) ...distributive
>
> A.B + C.(A'.B')' ...de Morgan's

I don't know if I'm heading in the write direction. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from where you left off:
$$
A \cdot B + C \cdot A' \cdot B + C \cdot A \cdot B' = \\
(C + C')A \cdot B + C \cdot A' \cdot B + C \cdot A \cdot B' =\\
C\cdot A \cdot B + C'\cdot A \cdot B + C \cdot A' \cdot B + C \cdot A \cdot B' =\\
C \cdot A \cdot (B + B') + A \cdot B\cdot (C + C')  = \\
A \cdot C + A \cdot B
$$
This kind of simplification is more typically done using [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).  The right-hand-side simplifies similarly:
$$
AB + CB + AC = \\
AC + AB + (A + A')CB = \\
AC + AB + ABC + A'BC = \\
AC(1 + B) + AB(1 + C) = \\
AC + AB
$$